# Which structure of MongoDB document considered to be better?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB, and I am trying to understand what document structure for nested documents is the best practice. 
For instance, what structure will be the best in my case - 
1)

```
"nonAssociatedFindings": {
      "finding": [
        {
          "name": "Non-mass enhancement (NME)",
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "Distribution",
              "value": "Focal"
            },
            {
              "name": "Internal enhancement patterns",
              "value": "Heterogeneous"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

or
2)

```
"nonAssociatedFindings": [
      {
        "name": "Non-mass enhancement (NME)",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "Distribution",
            "value": "Focal"
          },
          {
            "name": "Internal enhancement patterns",
            "value": "Heterogeneous"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Also, if you can suggest any good materials to learn essentials, besides documentation, I would appreciate it. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hard to answer without any information about "your case".

Comment: In short. Neither. You need to keep reading through the documentation and get to the parts where you start using the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) in either projection or update. Bottom line is that "nesting one array within another" is not good, and simply cannot be updated or queried effectively. The longer case here though is "best" is really subjective as to what your application needs to do. There is no such thing as "best practice" other than things that simply don't work within the current limitations.